# Update value in attribute table depending on the combination of few values in other table in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have one point layer and one table inside a GeoPackage. Let's say within the layer attribute table I have 4 columns (A, B, C and D) and in the table I have also 4 columns (E, F, G and H). The possible values of A are the same with the E, the B with the F and the C with the G.

What I want is that, depending on the values I introduce in A, B or C the row D is automatically updated looking at the table when A=E and B=F and C=G then take the H corresponding with this row and paste it into D.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to create a link based on three fields?

Comment: You may create a new field in each table that concatenate the field A, B, C and E, F, G then join your data based on these new field

Comment: Are there other rows in table.csv or only four rows?

Comment: More rows, like 70 or so! The 4 rows I did it as an example

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following script after adding point layer and table to QGIS.

```py
table = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("table_layer_name")[0]
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("point_layer_name")[0]

layer.startEditing()

# add new column named D. if it exists in the layer, delete the line below
layer.addAttribute(QgsField("D", QVariant.String, len=20))

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    filtre = f"E={f['A']} and F={f['B']} and G={f['C']}"
    
    try: 
        # Assuming one row matching the filter
        color = [r["H"] for r in table.getFeatures(filtre)][0]
    
    # if no matching row, the line below throws IndexError.
    # in this case, we should continue to the next feature
    except IndexError: 
        continue
    
    f["D"] = color
    layer.updateFeature(f) 

layer.commitChanges()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On attribut form, you can use Case expression as this
on field D

```
case 
 when "A" = '1' and "B" = '6' and "C" = '7' then 'Orange' 
 when "A" = '1' and "B" = '1' and "C" = '1' then 'GREEN'
 when "A" = '6' and "B" = '3' and "C" = '1' then 'RED'
end
```

[image]

Comment: or, shorter: `case 
when A || B || C = 111 then 'green'
when A || B || C = 123 then 'blue'
when A || B || C = 367 then 'orange'
when A || B || C = 631 then 'red'
end`

Comment: Or : `map_get (map('111','green','123','blue','367','orange','631','red'),A||B||C)`

Comment: what if there are many records in table.csv?

Comment: Which is the case. But I could take a bit of coffee and some music and try to write it all. Or is there any maximum number or coding rows I can write inside this expresion calculator?

Comment: Adding to this, I have to say that, using this approach I wouldnt need the CSV table inside the project. Right? 

Do you guys know if doing it like this will also populate the result when using QField?